# Google Sign-In from Fragment is not returned to the app

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-signin

The problem is Google Sign-In from Fragment closes the app and never calls `onActivityResult` both Fragment or parent Activity. When I start `signInIntent` as [described in example](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java) from my Fragment, the app closes and Sign-In dialog appears. I can choose an account to Sign-In, but after that I see just my desktop instead of my app.

Sign-In API Client configured using my parent Activity:

```
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
            .enableAutoManage(activity /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .build();
```

Add: Fragment parent Activity is not launch activity. In my launch activity I do Facebook sign-in operation and immediately `finish` it in case of a user already signed. Can the issue be in this place?

Comment: Paste your Activity and fragment here.

Comment: @SuhasBachewar no need to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was of `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` used in intent to launch the second Activity (parent of Fragment) from login Activity. Also, you can call `signInIntent` from Fragment and get `onActivityResult` there (you don't need call this intent from Activity).

Answer (score 0):

onActivityResult is called in you activity, add smth like this in your activity

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

and overide onActivityResult in your fragment

Comment: `onActivityResult` is never called in my Activity